# Combobox substitute inside material design

Tags: python-3.x, forms, material-design, kivymd, multiple-choice

My issue is it: I'm using kivymd, and trying to create a program using the material design ui. But I already have a program example, and inside this program I came across a combobox. In the otter interfaces, normally have a combobox, but when I search inside the M3 documentation, I don't find a combobox like widget. How the better way, that will stay more usefully, to the user have multiples choices. Such example this tuple of choices:

(`-----`, `Lucro Real`, `Lucro Presumed`, `Simples Nacional`, `Simples Nacional, gross revenue sub-limit excess`)

I see some widgets that do this choice, but I don't know what to use:

`Dropdown item`: seens like a combobox, but I doesn't find this widget inside material design documentation; 
`Selection components` (Radio button): It's a good choice, but I already used a radio button inside my form, and this can cause confusion; 
`Segmented controls`: It's very beautiful, but the label text is biggest, and that would take up a lot of space from the form.

If somebody know another widget, feel free to share.